# unable to assign value to a struct attribute. C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, struct, linked-list

I am trying to implement a linked list in C++. I have the following code

```cpp
class LinkedList {

private:
    struct node {
        int   data;
        node* next;
    }*
    head;

    node* mkNode(int data, node* next){
        
        node* n;
        n->data = data;
        n->next = next;

        return n;
    }

public:

    LinkedList(){
        head = NULL;
    }

    void insertAtHead(int data){
        head = mkNode(data, head);
    }
};
```

I am getting a `segmentation fault: 11` on the lines `n->data = data;` and `n->next = next;` inside the `mkNode()` function. any idea why?

Comment: This is _undefined behavior_: `node* n;  n->data = data;`. You must initialize `n` to some valid memory address, before using it.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: Assign a valid address of a `node`. struct to `n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
node* mkNode(int data, node* next) 
{
    node* n;
    n->data = data;
    n->next = next;
    return n;
}
```

pointer 'n' to 'node' is not initialized. Try to initialize it with struct node memory.

```
node* n = new struct node;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your pointer is not initialized.
Creating an Object on heap will solve this, don't forget to free the memory after use.

```
node* mkNode(int data, node* next){ return new node({data,next}); }
```